# How Build docker image from Jenkins Pipeline on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins

Here is my Jenkins File

```
https://gitlab.com/ThourayaLouati/docker-spring-boot/-/blob/master/Jenkinsfile
```

I have this error on Windows:

```
  open //./pipe/docker_engine: Le fichier spÃ©cifiÃ© 
  est introuvable. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

Any help please.
Kind regards.

Comment: As suggested in the error, have you tried checking if your docker is up and running ?

Comment: Yes, i use Quick start Terminal, ASUS@DESKTOP-41UCFB9 MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker-machine start
Starting "default"...
Machine "default" is already running.

Comment: I have installed Docker Desktop from scratch and it works fine. Thanks.